# How do I split a string on capitals unless preceded by a '+'

Tags: ruby, regex, split

I have a CamelCased string, which I would like to split into individual words at the capitals, unless the capital is preceded by a '+':

Splitting on the caps is fairly simple in Ruby:  `s.split(/(?=[A-Z])/)`
But I can't figure out how to add the "except after '+'" part.

For example:

```
s = "FooBashFizz+BuzzXBar"
p s.split(/(?=[A-Z])/)
=> ["Foo", "Bash", "Fizz+", "Buzz", "X", "Bar"]
```

desired:

```
=> ["Foo", "Bash", "Fizz+Buzz", "X", "Bar"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a negative lookbehind at the start.

```
irb(main):001:0> s = "FooBashFizz+BuzzXBar"
=> "FooBashFizz+BuzzXBar"
irb(main):002:0> s.split(/(?<!\+)(?=[A-Z])/)
=> ["Foo", "Bash", "Fizz+Buzz", "X", "Bar"]
```

**Explanation:**

- `(?<!\+)` Asserts that the preceding character would be any but not a `+` symbol.
- `(?=[A-Z])` Asserts that the following character must be an uppercase letter.

Comment: This wasn't working for me, until I tried irb1.9. Is there a 1.8 compatible solution?

Comment: Nice one, Avinash.  `?<!` occurred to me but `?=` was a pleasant surprise.

Comment: @CarySwoveland you're the one who encourages me every time whenever i touch the ruby tag. Thank you sooooooooo muchhhhh.. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Alternative using [`String#scan`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-scan). This also works in Ruby 1.8.

```
s = "FooBashFizz+BuzzXBar"
s.scan(/[A-Z][a-z]*(?:\+[A-Z][a-z]*)*/)
# => ["Foo", "Bash", "Fizz+Buzz", "X", "Bar"]
```